# My shoutbox vanishes on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, safari

So on Chrome and Safari my shoutbox completely vanishes after the page has loaded, most of the time. Making a reply brings it back. Can anyone help me fix this please?

This is how it should look:
[image]

This is how it looks:
[image]

It started after I changed the CSS of the inputs and made it all curvey. The URL is here:
http://www.creativeburrow.org

Comment: This happens on Safari too.

Comment: Darn. I've got no idea why.

Comment: I want to help you out but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your page in chrome, the shoutbox is there, but it has been pushed off the bottom of the screen.

If you hit F12 to bring up the inspector, and locate

```
<div id="nchat_admin_shoutbox" ...>
```

And reduce its width a touch, or reduce the margin-left, so it fits in the container, it will relocate back to its original position. So ... try narrowing it by a few pixels.

Or change the margin statement to

```
margin: 0 auto 5px;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works now :D.

Comment: Nope nevermind still not working. I even made it super small to test :(. When I change it in F12 it fixes but when the changes are loaded from the file it's the same thing.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like Chrome is generating errors every time it tries to update your chatbox. Chrome doesn't allow our AJAX calls to set the `content-length`, or `connection` header parameters as this can expose the site to certain security risks. See what happens when you comment out the lines in the script that set these values. ( at the bottom of the `function nchat_ajax()` function definition, just above the line `function nchat_parser(nchat)`

Comment: Okay so I found the code. It's not mine...

It's line 142. Is it okay to just remove them or..? Sorry Javascript is not something I've learned yet, not for another 6 months anyway.
http://pastebin.com/YihaEtVJ

Comment: I'm not certain that's the problem, but if you add two forward slashes, like `//` to the start of the line, that says the line is a comment, and won't be processed. then just remove the slashes to restore them if it doesn't work. in the file you posted, it's lines 144 and 145. `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);` and `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");`

Comment: Nope it's still happening on other machines. I'm not sure what to do lol.

Comment: Oops. This may take some debugging. here's some things to test: find the line that says `nchatOutput.innerHTML = nchat_content;` and change it to `jQuery(nchatOutput).html(nchat_content);` ... if that doesn't work try adding this after it: `jQuery(nchatOutput).hide().show();` , also, mark this answer as unselected, as the question isn't solved yet

Comment: So sorry it took so long to respond. Still not doing the trick. I have no idea what's doing this.